# Save data from contact form (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, email, contact-form

I have created a contact form using this tutorial. https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/rails-4-simple-form-and-mail-form-to-make-contact-form/

It works perfectly with the mailer. The tutorial however makes your model (in my case 'Share' model) inherit like so:

```
class Share < MailForm::Base
```

rather than the normal ActiveRecord::Base

I am guessing it is for this reason that when I try to save the data with

```
@article_save = Share.create(share_params)
```

I am getting an 'undefined create' method for class. My model looks like so:

```
class Share < MailForm::Base

attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
attribute :user_email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
attribute :title
attribute :message
attribute :source
attribute :url

#Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
#in ActionMailer accepts.
def headers
{
  :subject => "Article shared via email",
  :to => "my@email.com",
  :from => %(<#{email}>)
}
end
```

end

and my controller like so:

```
class SharesController < ApplicationController

def new
    @article = Share.new
end

def create
    @article = Share.new(params[:share])
    @article.request = request
    UserMailGenerator.new(nil).share_article(@article).deliver
    if @article.save
        redirect_to(:back)
    else
        render :new
    end
end


private

def share_params
  params.require(:share).permit(:email, :user_email, :url)
end

end
```

What would be the best way for me to keep this config and also save the data? I have already done the migrations to add the columns in the shared_params to the database.

Thanks

Comment: try to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base instead of MailForm::Base

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mail-form does not provide "create" method
If possible, changes your model as per given!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MailForm::Delivery

end
```

mail-form also play nicely with activerecord.

[Reference](https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form#playing-together-orms)

Comment: I actually ended up just using ActiveRecord::Base and sending the email with a different mailer. This makes complete sense though so thanks. Accepted for anyone else!